# ValueError: Cannot use median strategy with non-numeric data

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

The image shows that the column work class is converted to numerical value using dummy however when I print that column it still shows dtype as object[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yz3nf.png)
I am new to Data Science and learning on handling the missing values in Python version 3.8.
I came across this issue which I am not able to understand what went wrong.
The issue is that I created dummies for the column named 'work class' one of the values in this column is 'state-gov'. I created dummies for this column and the code worked fine till then. However, when I started imputing the missing values with median I received the following error.

ValueError: Cannot use median strategy with non-numeric data:
could not convert string to float: 'State-gov'

Please find the code from where I created dummies attached with this Question.
Thank You in advance for help!

```
todummy_list = ['workclass', 'education', 'marital-status', 'occupation', 'relationship', 'race', 'sex', 'native-country']
def dummy_list(data_frame_features, todummy_list):
for x in todummy_list:
    dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[x], prefix=x, dummy_na=False)
    data_frame_features = data_frame_features.drop(x, 1)
    data_frame_features = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
return data_frame_features
 # filling the missing values with median
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NAN', strategy='median', fill_value=None)
imp.fit(data_frame_features)
data_frame_features = pd.DataFrame(data=imp.transform(data_frame_features), columns=data_frame_features.columns)
print(f'\nRecalculated')
print(data_frame_features.isnull().sum().sort_values(ascending=False))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is being thrown because your workclass column contains "state-gov" (and potentially other string-type values) you cannot impute using the mean because mean imputation only works with numeric data. It looks like one imputation strategy which scikitlearn supports for string values is "most_frequent". If this is your desired behavior you can use that:

`imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NAN', strategy='median', fill_value=None)`

Your other option would be to fill all those NAN values with a constant value, in this case "work-from-home" for example:

`imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='NAN', strategy='constant', fill_value="work-from-home")`

Comment: Okay I understood what this does. The problem is this can work if there is one or two columns. If you check the code there are lot of columns and doing this for every single column will not be most efficient way to move ahead. Please correct me if I am wrong. As I am trying to fill Null values with the medical value of each column.

Comment: @SaloniShah If your columns held numeric values then you could use the SimpleImputer appropriately but because the columns are string values and that limits your options. I can't see any other way around iterating through all the relevant columns and determining what the appropriate fill value, and then filling it.

Comment: I know. and I am okay to convert to numeric. In fact using the dummies that's what I thought I did. If I am missing something then please let me know.